# Why can’t search for A in Elasticsearch to find the content, but AA can

Tags: elasticsearch

[image: Search A]
[image: Search AA]

When I search for "A" or "A 型", Elasticsearch cannot correctly read the English letter at the first position of the search string

Comment: Hi, if you'd be able to show mappings, queries, and sample data, that would be way more helpful than an image.